# Display filesize of custom field value

Tags: custom-field

I wanted to display the filesize of a document (pdf, word, excel etc) from a custom field. I already search and I found nothing. I got this code from other site but its in PHP. So I add it manually to my theme.

```
if($kpmFile !== get_post_custom_values("kpm_UploadFile")) {
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($kpmFile, TRUE));
echo $filesize = $head['content-length'];
}
```

I get this warning from above code:

```
Warning: get_headers() [function.get-headers]:
```

But if I make it like this:

```
if($kpmFile !== get_post_custom_values("kpm_UploadFile")) {
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers("http://example.net/publications/Wellspring-of-Hope.pdf", TRUE));
echo $filesize = $head['content-length'];
}
```

The code will show the filesize in 44147474 which the file is actually 42.1MB

I need help on how to display the correct file size of the document in kb, mb or gb from custom field value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 44147474 / 1024^2 = 42.1 --> simply divide by 1024 twice to go from bytes to MB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function to handle to show file size i.e.

paste this code in functions.php

```
   /*
 * @param string $fileSize Filepath
 * @param int $digits Digits to display
 * @return string|bool Size (KB, MB, GB, TB) or boolean
 */

function getFilesize($fileSize, $digits=2) {
    $sizes = array("TB","GB","MB","KB","B");
    $total = count($sizes);
    while ($total-- && $fileSize > 1024) {
        $fileSize /= 1024;
    }
return round($fileSize, $digits)." ".$sizes[$total];
}
```

paste this code in single.php

```
if($kpmFile !== get_post_custom_values("kpm_UploadFile")) {
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers("http://example.net/publications/Wellspring-of-Hope.pdf", TRUE));
echo $filesize = getFilesize($head['content-length']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ravs, sorry I forgot to mention that I am not good in PHP. I actually stumbled to that code but I dont know how to integrate the custom field.

Comment: answer updated check it and give a try

Comment: It display blank. Correct me if im wrong, the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$filePath; will display as "var/home/etc" right? but in my customfield is in "http://example.com/thefile.pdf"

Maybe thats is why in display blank?

Thanks

Comment: `$kpmFile` is it filepath url? print the output print_r($kpmFile) and share the result

Comment: Yes the $kpmFile is the file path. I tried print_r still show blank. :(

Comment: I think this means post meta value assign to post i.e. `kpm_UploadFile` is empty or not assign properly.I need to see more code

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/x8N6yPxk

Comment: let [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9638/lets-do-this)

Comment: Got problem. I dont have enough reputation to chat. Anyways here is the whole single post code: http://pastebin.com/bKWRbLe0

Hope you can help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you have live site?

Comment: http://drrknowledge.net/wellspring-of-hope-emerging-good-practice-on-disaster-preparedness-and-mitigation-in-typhoon-prone-philippine-regions/

Comment: i edit your single.php try it http://pastebin.com/DCRux1Yz

Comment: It still not showing. Please see URL

Comment: update my answer try it tested working on mine

Comment: try this single.php http://pastebin.com/d6gq2XHH

Comment: It shows 0B at my end

Comment: show your single.php

Comment: I just copied your edited single.php from pastebin

Comment: 0B came because your pdf file name contain space. `Wellspring of Hope.pdf`.please try it by `WellspringOfHope.pdf`

Comment: It works now thanks a lot for your patients and time :)